# Should it be so easy to inject javascript with a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, websecurity

As part of a security test, I have built a very basic Chrome extension with the purpose of being able to read secure cookies, as well as localStorage data. I managed to get this to work, which itself is a pretty bad thing, however, when building I used the following line:

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: '...'});`

Now, from my [understanding of this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs), this line of code will actually allow you to execute any javascript on the page, provided the user has agreed to the permissions of course.

With this, even with a CSP header on, anyone could quite easily create an extension to do what I have done above.

Should it be that easy to inject Javascript onto a webpage using an extension? Surely not!?

Bear in mind, I have the extension running in developer mode on my machine, and have not published it to the Chrome store, but I [haven't seen anything](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish) in regards to extensions being approved, just that they are approved and live immediately.

In case that it is possible by design for this to happen, are there any ways to prevent things like this happening?  Are there any CSP headers etc. that can help prevent this?

Many thanks all

Comment: AFAIK, browser extensions usually bypass all security features set on normal websites. I have plugins which change my DOM, add new functionality including widgets, make network requests etc. The only checks I see is the permission which the extension needs. If provided, the extension can pretty much do anything.

Comment: I though that was the case, however I was hoping that, as Google have put a lot into web security, there might have been something different when the extension isn't running in developer mode.  This seems like such a massive massive security issue for Google..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Chirag Ranvindra in a comment:

> browser extensions usually bypass all security features set on normal websites

Google states that users install Google Chrome Extensions **at their own risk**, which is the case for most software that allows plugins, addons, mods or the like.

To reduce the chance of a user installing an extension that is a potential risk, there are several warnings to the user, such as the requested permission before installing, reminders that "Developer" extensions can be a security risk, and as part of their Terms and Conditions, can and do deactivate extensions that violate their Extension Guidelines.

Refer to [The Google Chrome Terms and Conditions](https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/privacy/eula_text.html), specifically "20. Additional Terms for Extensions for Google Chrome".

As with any program you download, you should seriously consider if it's necessary to install, and if it's from a reputable developer. I'd recommend only installing extensions through the [Official Google Chrome Extensions Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/)

Comment: Cool, well the official line then it seems is that the onus is on the user, and the developers can do whatever they want!  Thanks for the reference to the guidelines etc., I will see if there are any preventative measures we can put in place.  Thanks again